# Однородны ли сказуемые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, сказуемые, тип-сказуемого

Не могу понять, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении.

*Леший может рассвирепеть на незадачливого путника(,) и будет крушить всё подряд.*

Являются ли сказуемые ***может рассвирепеть*** и ***будет крушить*** однородными, если грамматически относятся к разным временам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/rus_sprav?ajax=1&id=235) говорится о НАРУШЕНИЕ ВИДОВРЕМЕННОЙ СООТНЕСЁННОСТИ ГЛАГОЛОВ И ГЛАГОЛЬНЫХ ФОРМ. В таком случае ваше предложение можно немного изменить на *Леший **может рассвирепеть** на незадачливого путника и **начать крушить** всё подряд.*

А у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=208) сказано:

> Если союз **и** имеет присоединительное значение (с помощью этого союза
>   может присоединяться также неоднородный член предложения), то перед
>   ним ставится запятая: *[Лизавета Ивановна] разливала чай, и получала
>   выговоры за лишний расход сахара*; *она вслух читала романы, и виновата
>   была во всех ошибках автора*; *она сопровождала графиню в её прогулках,
>   и отвечала за погоду и за мостовую* (П.).

Получается, если союз **и** у вас в значении **и притом**, то это присоединительная конструкция, и запятая нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, Юлия. Посмотрю, осознаю.

Comment: Чтобы не возникло никаких вопросов по поводу правильности, я так и поступлю – заменю глагол будет на начать. Но в том материале сказано: _"...в ху­до­же­ствен­ной ли­те­ра­ту­ре... встре­ча­ют­ся от­ступ­ле­ния от этой нормы, но это все­гда сти­ли­сти­че­ски оправ­дан­но"_. Мне вот интересно, изначальное предложение может иметь право на существование без запятой? И вообще (даже с запятой, с присоединительным **и**), оно не кажется несколько корявым?

Comment: Я немного запинаюсь взглядом на _будет крушить_ , но, я думаю, тут нужен взгляд редактора (или более начитанного человека). Подождите ещё ответов)

Comment: Хотел подождать, поздно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос: **Являются ли сказуемые однородными, если грамматически относятся к разным временам?**

А почему же нет? Возьмем самый простой пример: *Он нашел интересную книгу и теперь  будет читать ее весь день*. Здесь разные временные формы у глаголов, но это не мешает сказуемым считаться **однородными**.

Однородность бывает чисто грамматическая, когда формы одинаковы, но очень часто глаголы **дифференцированы по семантике**. Соединительный союз И может иметь различные дополнительные значения: **временной очередности или взаимной обусловленности действий.** Во всех этих случаях сказуемые считаются однородными, запятая перед союзом И не ставится.

Чтобы союз И стал **присоединительным**, ему требуется особая семантика, а не грамматика, а именно выражение **добавочного значения**. По Розенталю, присоединительные члены предложения содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания.

***Леший может рассвирепеть на незадачливого путника и будет крушить всё подряд.***

Здесь между сказуемыми отнюдь не присоединительное значение (союз И ПРИТОМ подставить нельзя). Здесь выражена **взаимообусловленность и последовательность** действий, какое уж тут присоединение.

Поэтому это однородные сказуемые. Да и **по интонации** видно — неужели у вас есть желание обозначить паузу перед союзом И?

А вот **со стилистикой** вроде бы не всё в порядке. Дело, вероятно, в **модальном** глаголе.

Сравнить: ***Тогда леший рассвирепеет и будет крушить всё подряд.*** Так нормально.

Попробуем добавить наречие ***тогда***, которое яснее обозначит последовательность и обусловленность событий: ***Леший может рассвирепеть на незадачливого путника и тогда будет крушить всё подряд.*** Кажется тоже нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Comment: И всё, только спасибо? Хотелось бы услышать, полезен ли для вас был ответ, всё ли в нем понятно, со всем ли вы согласны, в том числе со стилистической правкой? Или эта тема вас уже не очень интересует?

Comment: Всё в порядке. Ответ развеял мои сомнения и пробелы; согласен, что стилистически изначальное предложение небезупречно.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос показался мне интересным в общем плане, кроме того, хотелось помочь разобраться  с вашими сомнениями. Ну и за мои старания  ответьте, пожалуйста, на мой вопрос: почему вы перестали активно работать на форуме? Это не простое любопытство, я бы его сформулировала  в общем плане: почему на форум не приходят новые люди, а если и приходят, то через некоторое время "исчезают".  Им здесь некомфортно, почему? Особенно жаль расставаться с некоторыми из них, для меня вы можете стать уже  третьим случаем за год. Выглядит  грустно. Это хорошая площадка, но ей очень не хватает новизны.

Comment: Sharon  Я писал ранее, что активность снизится после карантина, причём вышел я на новую работу – необходимо полное погружение туда. Отвечать я могу далеко не по всем темам. Например, этимология – очень интересно, но для меня лес дремучий, и почти всегда провоцирует споры. Мне больше важна практическая грамотность, пунктуация, строение предложений, орфография, может, ударение (отношусь спокойно к последнему). Надеюсь, что не пропаду, как некоторые, и на то, что смогу повышать свой уровень грамотности в других разделах языкознания. Не грустите :)

Comment: Думаю, что уходят люди отсюда потому, что не выдерживают конкуренции с более опытными и авторитетными. Начинают отвечать и видят, что ответы других обстоятельнее, "красивее", с собственным мнением, подкрепленным  доказательствами.Наступает спад, руки опускаются, соревновательный момент тоже сходит на нет, интерес к глубококопанию не выражен...

Comment: Спасибо, Александр,  за то, что нашли время и желание ответить. А мне вот очень не хватает новых людей. Я пришла сюда совсем другой и очень давно, еще на самый первый форум. Читаю сейчас свои ответы и не узнаю: они такие живые, эмоциональные. Потом  становились всё книжнее, умнее, а огонька уже не  было, как нет его и сейчас. И ни у кого нет… Все только учатся или учат, никто не любит язык просто так, без пользы для себя. Так его могут любить только вчерашние школьники со своими «идеями», поэтому с ними было интересно. "Живые души" - так хочется про них сказать.

Comment: Впрочем, взрослые «романтики» тоже встречались, да только не прижились здесь. Наверное, надо самой измениться, если здесь ничего не меняется. Когда-нибудь, потом… Спасибо еще раз, всё-таки приятно было с вами познакомиться. Желаю вам удачи во всех ваших делах, и буду следить за вашими успехами на форуме в режиме мониторинга. Примечание. А самооценку лучше всего установить на самом высоком уровне и там зафиксировать (здесь самый веселый смайлик, пусть он будет вашим талисманом).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваши слова!!!